# SqlException: Invalid column name, how to fix?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, database-migration

I added two new properties to my model, however when I try to run the project this error appears
[image]

How do I fis this? 
Here is my model Occorrencias:

```cs
    public class Ocorrencias
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string NomeFotografia { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Ignicao")]
        [Display(Name = "Ignicao")]
        public int IgnicaoFK { get; set; }
        public virtual Ignicoes Ignicao { get; set; }


    }
```

The project runs fine but it gives me also an error saying ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Comment: are you using entity framework code-first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the properties you added to the `Model` does not exist in the database.
you can use `add-migration` to update your database:

open `Package Manager Console` from Tools>NuGet Package Manage in visual studio and run command below to generate migration file. note that you must replace `<MigrationName>` with your proper Migration Name.

```
PM> Add-Migration <MigrationName>
```

and when the migration file created, use the following command to apply migration to database:

```
PM> Update-Database
```

Wait for the `Done.` to appear.